# Anyone knows in Teradata, if a value of a column is shown blank, but it is not null, not space, not ‘’, what can it be?

Tags: teradata

for example, I saw some blank value like this, but I cannot filter it out by using ‘is null’, ‘is space’, or ‘’, any idea what it is? [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQbI9.png)

Comment: If it's a VarChar column try `char2hexint(zipcode)` to see the binary representation.

Comment: cool! I see. thanks! Suppose it is a tab or something else, how to represent zipcode ^= 'Tab'? Does it mean I can only use the hex value to filter it out as a detour?

Comment: char2hexint returns a hex-string, e.g. `'09'` for tab. To search for this string use `'09'xc` , see https://docs.teradata.com/reader/~_sY_PYVxZzTnqKq45UXkQ/Yzw0Hnx8jUwZ0YmyVL9Otw